# Not able to deploy website on heroku. "Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/public'"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, heroku, web-deployment

After executing the command `git push heroku main` and then `heroku logs` , I am getting this error due to which websites are also not loading. Can someone please guide me why is this happening.

```
2022-09-27T08:48:48.846850+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538451+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:93
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538467+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err0;
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538467+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538468+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538468+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/public'
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538468+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1349:3)
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538468+00:00 app[web.1]: at sync (/app/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:74:13)
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538469+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.sync (/app/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:80:24)
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538470+00:00 app[web.1]: at new DiskStorage (/app/node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js:21:12)  
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538470+00:00 app[web.1]: at module.exports (/app/node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js:65:10)   
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538470+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Multer (/app/node_modules/multer/index.js:15:20)
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538470+00:00 app[web.1]: at multer (/app/node_modules/multer/index.js:95:12)
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538471+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:9:16)
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538471+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)        
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538471+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10) {                                                                                                          59:10) {
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538472+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -30,
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538472+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'mkdir',
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538472+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'EROFS',
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538473+00:00 app[web.1]: path: '/public'
2022-09-27T08:48:50.538473+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-09-27T08:48:50.697019+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-09-27T08:48:50.766554+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: It is saying that the app does not have sufficient permissions to write to the filesystem. The mkdir command is failing because the filesystem is read-only.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a directory in `/` in the first place? All of your code should live in `/app/`, or wherever else Heroku might choose to put it in the future. Use relative paths.

Comment: @Chris Not using relative path while requiring things in my app.js was the mistake. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @SuhasShenoy How did you solve the issue specifically? Having a same issue but I use relative path already `const publicDiretoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public/');`